# Why would we use static (fixed) port numbers in basic networking services?

Tags: sockets, networking, port

The one reason I can think of is that if we have fixed port numbers for specific services, we don't have to transmit that port number to the application to connect. It is already predefined in its specification and hence simplifies our connections.

Are they any other reasons why we would use static port numbers?

Comment: If you use a load balancer you don't have to send the port.  Have clients talk to the load balancer and let it do port mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the reason. If you don't have a fixed port number you *can't* transmit it to the application, as it doesn't know how to connect to you. You would need something like the old RPC `portmapper` server, or the RMI Registry, that runs on a fixed port, that can be asked to supply connection details for a specific service.

This is also why we have URLs with multiple paths all serviced by the same HTTP server, or servlet container.

Comment: Fixed port numbers seems pretty silly today, but it made sense back when there were only a few services available. In hindsight, transmitting an application name in the first packet, or at least having 32-bit port numbers, might have been better.

Comment: @EricS A portmapper that worked beyond RPC would have been better.